# What are the Transmuting formulas in Torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

Does anyone have a full list of transmuting formulas?  How do you unlock them?

Comment: I believe if you scroll over the recipe box (which will be dark when you haven't used it yet) it will actually instruct you how to unlock it. There are only 7 or so core recipes.

Comment: The reason I asked was I did 3 giant potions to do a super potion, which wasn't originally shown to me, so I was wondering if there were other "hidden" ones.

Comment: The hidden ones follow the same formula as the shown recipes. For example, the tier of health potions doesn't matter, any three health potions will combine into a better one (until there is no longer a higher tier, that is). Same as the level of gem doesn't matter, 3 will be combined into an alternate gem of equal level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You unlock them simply by using them once. I know of no 'officially complete' list, but the one over on wikia should cover the core recipes.

http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Transmuting_%28T2%29

Comment: It would be best to paste the most relevant recipes into the body of this answer.